# How to match all numerical characters and some single characters using regex

Tags: java, regex, string, match

How can I match all numbers along with specific characters in a String using regex? I have this so far

```
if (!s.matches("[0-9]+")) return false;
```

I don't understand much regex, but this matches all characters from 0-9 and now I need to be able to match other specific characters, for example "/", ":", "$"

Comment: Put them in the character class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex by including those symbols in a `character class`:

```
s.matches("[0-9$/:]+")
```

[Read more about character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the other characters that you need to match to the end of the character group, like this:

```
if (!s.matches("[0-9/:$]+")) return false;
```

You need to be careful about several things:

- If `^` is among the characters, it must not be the first one of the group
- If `-` is among the characters, it must be the last one in the group
- If `]` is among the characters, it needs to be escaped for regex and for Java, e.g. `[\\]]`
- If `\` is among the characters, it needs to be escaped for regex and for Java, e.g. `[\\\\]`

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
String regex = "\\d/:$+";
```